# How to upgrade the Linux mainline 3.3.6 kernel?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, kernel

I want to install the latest stable Linux Kernel 3.3.6. Can someone please help me with a step by step guide? Thanks in advance

BTW I'm on a 64bit system and I have downloaded the following `amd64`debs from 
[kernel.ubuntu.com](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3.6-precise/):

```
linux-headers-3.3.6-030306-generic_3.3.6-030306.201205121335_amd64.deb

linux-headers-3.3.6-030306_3.3.6-030306.201205121335_all.deb

linux-image-3.3.6-030306-generic_3.3.6-030306.201205121335_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Sees ".deb" extension. Have you tried installing it using `sudo dpkg -i` or the GUI package manager...?

Comment: I have downloaded the 3 '.debs' which I'm told I need. Do I just install those 3 '.debs' to upgrade the kernel to 3.3.6 or do I have to do something different?

Comment: Install & Reboot.

Comment: In what order should I install the '.debs' as I just read the order is: 1. Headers-all  2. Headers 3. Image. Is this true?

Comment: If you have any out-of-tree modules, it's indeed headers-all/headers followed by image. Otherwise it does not matter. You can pass multiple packages to dpkg: `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

Comment: so if I get what you are saying this is what I have to do: (1) cd ~/Desktop/kernel (I created a 'kernel' folder on my desktop and place the 3 .debs in it) (2) sudo dpkg -i *.deb (3) Reboot?

Comment: Exactly. Installing a kernel package is no more different from installing the same kernel through the repos.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I now running the 3.3.6 kernel, can you please post your answer so I select it as the best answer?

Comment: This question is one of the many duplicates of a commonly asked question, you may accept one of the answers below; I won't post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can double click each to install them in either the software center or gdebi, whatever your default is. However, I encourage you NOT to do this unless you have a specific reason for wanting this kernel. Canonical heavily patches their kernels to make it play nice with their system and you may wind up with a lack of drivers. You could compile your own kernel and manually add the Ubuntu patches and this would be a safer route. Kernel source is located at [www.kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org).

For a guide on compiling your own kernel, visit https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile as it is pretty in-depth.

Comment: So far no issues only powertop program doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You want to get it from here

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3.6-precise/

sudo dpkg -i *.deb